# Span at start of paragraph in Jade

Tags: html, pug

Im new to Jade and this is probably easy but I've been unable to achieve what I want. The end HTML should look like:

```
<p class='address'>
    <span class='strong'>
        Starting Point:
    </span>
15 Yemen Road, Yemen
</p>
```

My jade is:

```
p.address 
    span.strong 
    |Starting Point:
|15 Yemen Road, Yemen
```

But this results in the html:

```
<p class="address"> 
    <span class="strong"> </span>
    Starting Point:
</p>
15 Yemen Road, Yemen
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Please remember In jade templates spacing is very impairment. If you have any clarifications see http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is apparently important:

```
p.address 
    span.strong 
        |Starting Point:
    |15 Yemen Road, Yemen
```

Will work